# Pivot Table filter criteria by a data array using google sheets (script) problems

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, pivot

What I am trying to do is this, we get data dumped into a prepaid file on google sheets with someone inputting the "From date", meaning this prepaid item is scheduled to start getting moved to expenses on X month. The example for March is the file that I have has obviously March dates, and even months including prior to 2019 (because it's prepaid), and I also have April and May dates because invoices get submitted early. What I'm trying to do is to create a google script that filters on everything less than current month to be able to post the correct time frame (so I only want to pivot on March and before March data.

Here is my loop..

```
function PivotTest() {
 var pull = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Pull");
 var lr = pull.getLastRow();
 var criteriadate = pull.getRange(2,1).getValue();
 var pullrawdata = pull.getRange(5,31,lr,1).getValues();
 var Pulld= []
 for (var i = 0; i< pullrawdata.length ; i++){ 
 if (pullrawdata[i][0] <= criteriadate)
 {
  Pulld.push(pullrawdata[i])
 }
}
```

Where criteriadate is a formula for the month that we are in (eomonth(today(),0);
Then I have a bunch of lines adding my other pivot table info(my critera is at the bottom) of the code...

`var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setVisibleValues([Pulld])
    .build();
    pivotTable.addFilter(31, criteria);`

Pullrawdata is the dates of the dataset or the "From date", and I keep trying to move them to a similar format but the problem is when my pivot table gets created it doesn't filter by anything, so I go to show my output of Pulld array and it is completely different format then the data formatting of the date, which is therefore different then the criteriadate. I am stumped, please help. Am I not able to filter on visible values by an array, even though when I display the array it is correct, as in doesn't include April/May data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Instead of using the dates as filter I converted the dates to milliseconds and used that as the filter. That corrected the output of the formatting issue so the criteriadate was the same format as the Pulld array and it worked to complete the filter that way.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

### How to compare dates

Date objects cannot be directly compared to each other.

What you can do instead, is to use the function [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) that converts dates into ms since Unix Epoch.

Sample:

`if (pullrawdata[i][0].getTime() <= criteriadate.getTime()){...`

Note that `getTime()` will only work if the objects to which it is applied are formatted in a way to correctly recognized as dates - if it is applied to a string, it will throw you an error.

Comment: Hi Ziganotschka and thank you, can you clarify this comment? I was skeptical that it's the answer I'm looking for but I did try to incorporate the gettime() in my efforts and was unsuccessful. Maybe I'm not thinking outside the box enough on this one but my for statement and output of Pulld gives me exactly what I need, but the output is Tue, Mar 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Pacific etc) and the pivot table selection is only 3/31/2020 (formatted like the original data). So I think this is why it's not selecting any criteria at all because of that difference?? I could be wrong

Comment: Is `3/31/2020` a date object or a string? You can test it with Logger.log(typeof "name of your variable"); If it is not recognized correctly as a date, you can convert it from string to date with `var newDate = new Date(datestring);`

Comment: And I can't apply the getTime() method to the array of Pulld since to change my output since it has multiple selections. I'm sure that reason is because an array is considered a string?

Comment: You do not need to apply `getTime()` to the whole array - only to the date object that you want to compare.

Comment: I must not be converting the items correctly because when I try to use it on criteriadate and pulld they both return object, even without the conversion. I'm sorry, this portion is obviously new to me.

Comment: `object` is the correct type for a date object. In any case, you can wrap them in e.g. `var newcriteriadate = new Date(criteriadate)` to make sure that they are correctly recognized as date object.

Comment: So since both criteriadate and the Pulld date are objects, how is the pivot filter creation unable to recognize that Pulld as an array has 2 items that I want to make visible in my pivot filter (since they are <= criteriadate)? I try to change stuff to get criteriadate close to the output of Pulld format, but even then my filters aren't selected.

Comment: I can't really to tell you what the exact problem with your data is without seeing your spreadsheet.

Comment: I unfortunately can't give access to it, but if there's a different method to completing this that I could use that would be helpful. All I want to do is create a new pivot table each time, but filter directly on data prior to and including the current month we are in. So there's an infinite number of variables involved, and the variables obviously change next month. If I need to be doing something other than a for loop I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Once again, it's hard without seeing your data, but I can see to other problems in you code. 1: `var pullrawdata` soudl be `= pull.getRange(5,3,lr-5+1,1).getValues();`m not `getRange(5,3,lr,1)` 2: `Pulld.push(pullrawdata[i])` and `.setVisibleValues([Pulld])` assigns to `setVisibleValues` the 3D array ` [[[...], [...], [...]]]` instead of the expected 1D array.